# Method HtmlHelper::tableheader does not exist [CORE\cake\libs\view\helper.php, line 154]

Tags: cakephp, html-helper, tableheader

i am using cake php and i need that use tableheader but i face with this error

```
Method HtmlHelper::tableheader does not exist [CORE\cake\libs\view\helper.php, line 154]
```

code is :

```
$th = array ('sggs','ba','aa');
echo $this->Html->tableheader($th);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelling mystake of  "tableHeaders"

```
$th = array ('sggs','ba','aa');

echo $this->Html->tableHeaders($th);
```

Comment: my view recognize $html->link()
but not recognize tableheader

Comment: thanks chetan , but this output is string and not table
by thanks.